# Problems with MongoDB query

Tags: codeigniter, oauth

I am developing an API using Codeigniter and Alex Bilbies oAuth2 and MongoDB libraries.
I need to do a MongoDB query where I do a query for a document with _id of 1 and access token is null.

I have this so far but it does not work:

```
$exists_query = $this->CI->mongo_db->select('access_token')->where(array('_id' => $session_id, 'access_token' != NULL))->get('oauth_sessions');
```

I tried this too:

```
$exists_query = $this->CI->mongo_db->select('access_token')->where(array('_id' => $session_id))->where_not_equal('access_token', NULL)->get('oauth_sessions');
```

How can I change this query to work?

Answer (score 0):

This seems weird.. Are you not using the id's that mongo provides??

If you are, you have to use the special mongoid function that converts raw string into a mongo id. If your not using the default mongoid... than you really should!

Also why are you having to set nulls?? Mongo is very structure unspecific, if a field isn't used you dont need to set a null value to it.. just dont include that field.. this isn't mysql where you need to store null values.. each row in the mongo db can have different columns.. that way when you are querying the db you can use the native method in mongo to check is a field exists..

Use mongo the way it should be used.. and you wont have these issues you are having

Your query should look something like like

```
$this->CI->mongo_db->select('access_token')->where(array( '_id' => MongoId($session_id), exists => array('access_token' => -1)))->get('oauth_sessions');
```